# Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in Content Security Pol

Tags: reactjs, electron

What is the content security policy for an electron react typescript application?
I'm not even using 'unsafe-eval' and I'm getting an error.
Here are some Content Security Policies that I've tried and received the above error message.

-->
     -->

Comment: <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'unsafe-inline'" />
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self';">  -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'"> -->

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because you're trying to do an `unsafe-eval`, but it is disallowed by your Content Security Policy.

You should **not** be using **unsafe-eval**, hence it is named *unsafe*.

This means, do not call `eval()` or `Function()`, and do not pass strings to `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or `setImmediate`. These can leave your application vulnerable to serious security flaws, and if you don't 110% understand what you're doing, you should avoid doing these instead of getting around the error by adjusting your CSP.

---

If you absolutely must continue without heeding the above warning, you can allow `unsafe-eval`.

To do so, add `unsafe-eval` like this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'unsafe-eval'">
```